# replacement of prelude function minimum causes error

Tags: haskell

I am trying to implement selection sort but I am running into an issue whenever I use my own function `minim` it crashes even tho that it also returns the same value as the `minimum` function from prelude.

```
rmf :: Eq t => t -> [t] -> [t]
rmf  _ [] = []
rmf oc (h : t)
      | oc  == h = t
      |otherwise = h : rmf  oc t

mymin :: Int -> Int -> Int
mymin a b
    | a > b  = b
    | a < b  = a
    | a == b = a

minim :: [Int] -> Int
minim [a]  = a
minim (h:t)  = mymin h (minim t)

seqSort :: (Eq a, Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
seqSort [] = []
seqSort xs = s : seqSort (rmf s xs)
    where s = minimum xs

main :: IO ()
main = print(seqSort [
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
minim :: [Int] -> Int
```

This function works on lists of integers. Not on any other lists -- only lists of *integers*.

```
seqSort :: (Eq a, Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
```

This function works on lists of any ordered type. On lists of integers, but also lists of booleans, of strings, etc. Hence, this function can not use `minim` which only works in a specific sub-case.

Solution: generalize the type of `minim` accordingly. You'll have to also fix `mymin` similarly.

As a final note, remember to post the error. Debugging this would have been much easier with the error at hand:

```
    * Couldn't match type `a' with `Int'
      Expected: [Int]
        Actual: [a]
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          seqSort :: forall a. (Eq a, Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
        at <source>:19:1-38
    * In the first argument of `minim', namely `xs'
      In the expression: minim xs
      In an equation for `s': s = minim xs
    * Relevant bindings include
        xs :: [a] (bound at <source>:21:9)
        seqSort :: [a] -> [a] (bound at <source>:20:1)
   |
22 |     where s = minim xs
   |                     ^^
```

Note the part

```
      Expected: [Int]
        Actual: [a]
```

complaining that `minim` only accepts `[Int]` and won't take an `[a]`. That's the issue.

Comment: can you maybe please show me an idea how you would fix  minim please i am new to haskell and i am rather stuck

Comment: @xsssssudjdfi Just change their type: use `a` instead of `Int`, and require `(Eq a, Ord a) =>` as done for `seqSort`. The rest of their code should already be ok with the new type.

Comment: Type declarations in Haskell use type variables like 'a'. Types have a capital first letter - type variables, like functions, have a lower case first letter. Then, when you come to use the function, the real type is inserted there. A bit like templates in C++.

Comment: I believe the illegible part like "'a' is a rigid type variable ..." would be improved in future GHC versions.